# Google maps AS3 API: How do I move the position controls?

Tags: google-maps, controls, move

how do I move the positionControl in a flash google map using the AS3 api?

Answer (score 0):

```
map.clearControls();

var positionControlOptions:PositionControlOptions = new PositionControlOptions({buttonSize: new Point(17, 17),buttonStyle: new ButtonStyle({}),buttonSpacing: new Point(4, 4),position: new ControlPosition(ControlPosition.ANCHOR_BOTTOM_LEFT, 10,30)});

map.addControl(new PositionControl(positionControlOptions));
```